# Printing to the terminal in a encoding neutral manner

Tags: c, locale, fwrite, utf

I would like to print a string to the screen regardless of its encoding (UTF-8,16,32). This string is represented in a char array so I need to ignore null bytes and carry on printing to stdout; this puts printf family and friends out of the question.

```
char text[] = { 0x00, 0x55, 0x00, 0x6E, 0x00, 0x69, 0x00, 0x63, 0x00, 0x6F, 0x00, 0x64, 0x00, 0x65 };

fwrite( text, sizeof(char), sizeof(text), stdout );
```

To this end I've chosen the above solution to give me the ability to print all UTF encoding formats. I understand that certain terminals will not display the characters correctly but that is not my concern as its a configurable option outside of the application.

My application has settings on which message catalogue to load (en_EN.UTF-8, etc..) however I want to avoid having to do string conversion in the code based on the currently selected locale.

Could I please get a review on this approach before I let it go live?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. When you deal with text, encoding matters big time. So you must do conversion.

And it is also bad to keep things in a char array, you should use a byte array. Because:

- If not already defined in some header, you should define (or typedef) byte as unsigned char. Plain char can be signed or unsigned, and you will have surprises.
- More readable, as it makes the intent clear. I see byte, it is a bunch of bytes. I see char, it is plain text (and in your case, it is obviously not the case)

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand you. On the readability with a byte array I see the point. However your comment that I need to convert the string. If a terminal takes utf16 encoded characters and I write a array of bytes representing utf16 this should still display correctly. If I then alter the terminal to a utf8 encoding and load a utf8 string this again should display. no?

Comment: @Ben If terminal accepts utf16 in big-endian mode and you pass array of bytes encoded in little-endian,- then answer is NO, this will not display correctly on terminal.

Comment: Ok thanks for Ur time. This is the point of selecting based on The locale

Comment: @Ben: If the terminal uses UTF-16 and your array contains the bytes for UTF-16, you might be ok. But my understanding was that you want to use that same array for any terminal setting. But even if you use "UTF-16LE bytes" for UTF-16LE terminal, "UTF-8 bytes" for UTf-8 terminal and so on, it is still not guaranteed that a function like fwrite will go thru the same "pipeline" as a normal printf, who is "terminal aware", so you might still have problems with complex scripts (for instance), even if "the bytes are right".

Answer (score 0):

What if you defined char array in Big-Endian mode and terminal accepts Little-Endian ? Or [vice-versa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) ? 
I too think, that you can't live without conversion when dealing with `char -> Utf` thing (only because of endianness). Also its reasonable to make define some

```
typedef unsigned char  utf8char;
typedef unsigned short utf16char;
typedef unsigned int   utf32char;
```

And

```
typedef enum {
   BIG_ENDIAN,
   LITTLE_ENDIAN
} CHAR_ENDIANNESS
```

In that way you will make conversion to UTF more transparent , debug will be easier and code maintenance will improve too.